# Is there a method to automatically change the orientation of an image to 0 degrees if it's disoriented using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to determine the orientation of an input image automatically while an image is read. Is there a method according to which in case of any disorientation in the image the output image is automatically rotated to 0 degrees?
I found out this article on [Phase Correlation](https://in.mathworks.com/help/images/use-phase-correlation-as-preprocessing-step-in-registration.html) but it uses an already fixed image and then compares with the disoriented image. Is there any direct method?

I'm completely new to MATLAB so any help or suggestions would be great.

Comment: How do you measure orientation?

Comment: I referred this article to find the orientation https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/124994-detecting-orientation-symmetry-in-an-image

Comment: Once you know the rotation, just use `imrotate(img,angles)`. Knowing the rotation is not straightforward though.... That example you showed only works for that specific image.

Comment: @AnderBiguri , yeah. I'm getting wrong orientation results for other sample images like you mentioned.

Comment: @Ranit yes, but how to solve that is a different question that what you asked, plus probably one without an answer. What is the rotation of this image? https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Basketball.jpeg/220px-Basketball.jpeg

Comment: @AnderBiguri, the result i'm getting is -89.3906.

Comment: I am not asking you to run the code... I am proposing a thought exercise: what is the rotation, according to you, of that image? You may come to realise that you can not answer that question for every image that exist.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Got it. It's difficult to tell the orientation because we are not aware of the initial orientation. It's ambiguous. 
Really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.